# Trying to create video from multiple frames

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to create a video from multiple frames (captured by opencv and ingested into kafka). I receive a byte string of the image (frame) and have verified that it's valid (by writing to a jpeg, showing with `cv2.imshow(..)`, etc). What I cannot seem to conquer is creating a video clip from multiple frames.

Here is my current code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('cam', bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('test.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (1920, 1080))
i = 0

for message in consumer:

    print("message.topic=%s, message.partition=%d, message.offset=%d, key=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,
                                                                                 message.offset, message.key))
    i += 1

    if i == 50:
        break

    nparr = np.fromstring(message.value, np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    cv2.imshow('THIS IS THE CURRENT FRAME', img)

    out.write(img)

    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):  # Hit `q` to exit
        break

out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any tips/help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested some similar code on my machine and found a couple potential issues:

OpenCV silently refuses to write data to the VideoWriter if your `img` is not exactly the correct dimensions (1920, 1080 in this case). Try something like `img = cv2.resize(img, (1920, 1080))` before writing to the output.

The codec referenced by your FOURCC may not exist - if you check `out.isOpened()` you should be able to discover if that is the issue.